# Why is this inaccessible or unknown property error occuring?

Tags: java, excel, jxls

I'm using Jxls to export the results of some tests. On the first one, everything is working fine :

```
    private void exportDataDet(File file) throws ParseException, IOException, ParsePropertyException, InvalidFormatException {

    List<ResultsDetails> detRes = generateResultsDetails();
    String age = com.app.MenuInfoSujet.getTfAge().getText();
    int ageSujet = Integer.parseInt(age);
    String nivEtu = com.app.MenuInfoSujet.getTfNbreAnneesEtude().getText();
    int nivEtuSujet = Integer.parseInt(nivEtu);


    if(ageSujet < 30 && nivEtuSujet <13){
        try(InputStream is = IdGenre.class.getResourceAsStream("/xlsTemplates/IdGenre/IdGenre_20-29-et=12.xlsx")) {
            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(IdGenre)) {
                Context context = new Context();
                context.putVar("detRes", detRes);
                JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, os, context);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            }
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

But one the second one, I keep having the `inaccessible or unknown property` :

```
   private void exportDataDet(File file) throws ParseException, IOException, ParsePropertyException, InvalidFormatException {

    List<ResultsDetails> detRes = generateResultsDetails();
    String sexe = com.app.MenuInfoSujet.getSexe();
    String sujetFemme = new String ("Femme");
    String sujetHomme = new String ("Homme");
    String age = com.app.MenuInfoSujet.getTfAge().getText();
    int ageSujet = Integer.parseInt(age);

    if(sexe.equals(sujetFemme) && ageSujet < 40){
        try(InputStream is = PercepHumour.class.getResourceAsStream("/xlsTemplates/PercepHumour/IdHumF20-39VO.xlsx")) {
            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(PercepHumour)) {
                Context context = new Context();
                context.putVar("detRes", detRes);
                JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, os, context);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            }
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

The ResultsDetails list is the same one, just a different class, as the two tests are in different class.

```
    private List<ResultsDetails> generateResultsDetails() throws ParseException {

    List<ResultsDetails> resDet = new ArrayList<ResultsDetails>();
    for(int i=0; i<tableau.getRowCount(); i++){
        ResultsDetails newRes = new ResultsDetails(item[i], rep[i], justefaux[i], tempsrep[i]);
        item[i]=((DataPercepHumour) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
        rep[i]=((DataPercepHumour) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
        justefaux[i]=((DataPercepHumour) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
        tempsrep[i]=((DataPercepHumour) tableau.getModel()).getValueAt(i, 5).toString();
        resDet.add(newRes);
    }
    return resDet;
}
```

The data inside these lists are of the exact same type : item is like "femme" or "drôle", rep is like "homme" or "drôle" (it's the answer of the patient), justefaux is like "0" or "1", tempsrep is like "762" or "1462" (a time in millisecond in double convert to string).

The excel sheets are processed with the exact same method, it's a copy/paste actually. So the comment are in the first cell `jx:area(lastCell="D2")` , and in the A2 `jx:each(items="detRes" var="detRes" lastCell="D2")`. The cell being processed with formulas like `${detRes.itemResult}` .

Again, it's the same thing everywhere, but it just works on the IdGenre test. I've tried with different names, but the error keeps coming. I've seen that it's possible to silent mode on JExl engine (https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/41/myclassproperty-inaccessible-or-unknown), but I don't know how to activate it with the JxlsHelper I'm using.

There's no stacktrace, just the log of Jxls. For the working condition:

```
09:48:13.966 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory - Transformer class is org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer
09:48:15.079 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.jxls.area.XlsArea - Applying XlsArea at détails!A1 with Context{detRes=[com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@63eea71d, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@62cb766d, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@566494f6, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@3d478ece, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@2b871034, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@12467337, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@607786ad, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@61474593, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@7252ff3f, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@532ce589, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@fb253af, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@5482e417, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@31cc42bf, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@578f9a2, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@18cafd89, com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@5b2b10db]}
09:48:15.177 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.jxls.area.XlsArea - Applying XlsArea at détails!A2 with Context{detRes=com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@63eea71d}
09:48:15.194 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.jxls.area.XlsArea - Applying XlsArea at détails!A3 with Context{detRes=com.epreuvesVO.IdGenre$ResultsDetails@62cb766d}
...
```

It goes on until until the entire list is passed on.

And for the non-working condition:

```
09:04:25.107 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory - Transformer class is org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer
09:04:26.165 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.jxls.area.XlsArea - Applying XlsArea at détails!A1 with Context{detResPH=[com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@55f82b5f, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@452287d9, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@747bc1a2, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@b3414ea, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@1f827400, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@4e4f3466, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@64139adc, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@4fab41f0, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@43051e71, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@74deee73, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@ce34f4e, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@19522be3, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@724f482e, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@71e18d62, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@676e352f, com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@6feb1712]}
09:04:26.276 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.jxls.area.XlsArea - Applying XlsArea at détails!A2 with Context{detResPH=com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@55f82b5f}
09:04:26.291 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN  org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine - org.jxls.expression.JexlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate@61![0,19]: 'detResPH.itemResult;' inaccessible or unknown property detResPH
09:04:26.293 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN  org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine - org.jxls.expression.JexlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate@61![0,18]: 'detResPH.repResult;' inaccessible or unknown property detResPH
09:04:26.295 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN  org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine - org.jxls.expression.JexlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate@61![0,24]: 'detResPH.justeFauxResult;' inaccessible or unknown property detResPH
09:04:26.296 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN  org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine - org.jxls.expression.JexlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate@61![0,23]: 'detResPH.tempsRepResult;' inaccessible or unknown property detResPH
09:04:26.297 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.jxls.area.XlsArea - Applying XlsArea at détails!A3 with Context{detResPH=com.epreuvesVO.PercepHumour$ResultsDetails@452287d9}
09:04:26.298 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN  org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine - org.jxls.expression.JexlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate@61![0,19]: 'detResPH.itemResult;' inaccessible or unknown property detResPH
09:04:26.299 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN  org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine - org.jxls.expression.JexlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate@61![0,18]: 'detResPH.repResult;' inaccessible or unknown property detResPH
09:04:26.300 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN  org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine - org.jxls.expression.JexlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate@61![0,24]: 'detResPH.justeFauxResult;' inaccessible or unknown property detResPH
09:04:26.301 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN  org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlEngine - org.jxls.expression.JexlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate@61![0,23]: 'detResPH.tempsRepResult;' inaccessible or unknown property detResPH
...
```

And it goes through the ResultsDetails list.

If anyone has any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Please add complete stacktrace and point the line in code where it is occurring

Comment: Thing is that I don't have any stack trace, just the log of Jxls. I update the question with it.

Comment: The community [recently discussed begging for urgency](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), and has firmly decided it is unacceptable. I'd not recommend you do this on _any_ volunteer-driven source of help on the web.

Comment: Alright, sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Unfortunatelly, the Jxsl has very limited error issues. If the result is in proper format I advice to simply ignore it. There are only the warnings.

```
    2018-06-29 20:04:56,922 WARN  [http-bio-8989-exec-6] JexlEngine - org.jxls.expression.JexlExpressionEvaluator.evaluate@61![0,10]: 'log.reason;' inaccessible or unknown property log
...
```

Unfortunately, the issues are proportionately to the number of generated rows. If the output is not fit properly, try to check everything again. I have had one character more in template comment, the issues were vague - they doesn't helped me.